# Jquery: Toggle closest parent element using .on("click")?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-traversing

Given HTML such as

```
<div class="tpl grey">Hosts:
    <p>Hi !</p>
    <p>How are you ?</p>
    <p>What ever.</p>
    <a href="./~">An other child & element type !</a>
</div>
```

How to make that a click on a child element toggle the `class="grey"` of the closest parent `.tpl` element ?

---

The following code fails :

```
//Action to do on parent $(".tpl") 
var switch1 = function () {
    $(this).closest(".tpl").toggleClass("blue grey");
}

// On() click event
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".tpl").on("click", "p", switch1() );
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/MRcCy/1

Comment: `$(".tpl").on("click", "*", switch1() )` should be better so it works on all child element (*)

Comment: Change `$(".tpl").on("click", "p", switch1() );` to `$(".tpl").on("click", "p", switch1 );` http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/MRcCy/2/

Comment: If you have code such as `foo(bar())`, then `bar` is executed *first* and it's return value is passed to `foo`. Arguments are always evaluated first.

Comment: @FelixKling: Oh, true, that explain it thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to toggle the closest .tpl (even though i only see one) try this

`$(document).ready(function() {
         $(".tpl p").click(function(){
             $(this).closest('.tpl').toggleClass('grey');
         });
    });`

Answer (score 1):

**[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MRcCy/4/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tpl").click(function(){
        $('.tpl').toggleClass('grey blue');
    });
});
```